# RAD Studio XE 2010 : Graphics32 compilation problem

Tags: delphi, installation, delphi-xe

I'm trying to install Graphics32 to my freshly installed Embarcadero RAD Studio XE.
I just open GR32_DSGN_RS2010.bpl and I try to compile it.

I get this error :

> [DCC Erreur] GR32.inc(172): E2029 Déclaration attendu(e) mais constante chaîne trouvé(e)

Which means

```
[DCC Erreur] GR32.inc(172): E2029 Declaration expected but constant found instead
```

It's here:

```
{$IFNDEF COMPILER6}
{$IFNDEF FPC}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
'  Graphics32 may only be installed with Delphi/BCB 6 (or higher)    '
'   or Free Pascal / Lazarus                                         '
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
{$ENDIF}
{$ENDIF}
```

So it seems like there's a "define" problem.
Any idea where I should look / what I should modify to make it work?

Comment: Have you tried installing `GR32_RS2010.bpl` first and then `GR32_DSGN_RS2010.bpl`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the current 1.9 release doesn't correctly support XE. Ther error you see is probably because the .INC file fails to detect the new compiler version.

I found [this upload on sourceforge,](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3067509&group_id=112985&atid=663800) which has 'compatibility fixes' for Graphics32 on XE.

> I have got adapted GR32 for Delphi XE. There is compatibility changes.

As an alternative, you could get the latest source snapshot directly from the [project SVN server](http://graphics32.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/graphics32/trunk/). It seems that version has XE supported included.

No warranty expressed or implied, though. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much I'll take a look at the latest source

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have an old version of graphics32 which doesn't have up to date conditional definitions for recent Delphi versions in the GR32.inc include file.

<strike>Simplest solution is to download the latest graphics32 which has been updated for XE.</strike>

It seems you have to get the latest development version for XE compatibility.

Comment: Hopefully this will become the correct answer in the future when they make a release newer than 1.9.

Answer (score 0):

Much as I haven't installed Graphics32 into mine, you can just comment out all those lines :) Take it from there.